# Update a LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime value from code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some xaml like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="sbLogo" x:Key="onLoadeducLogo" Completed="sbLogo_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="pauseKeyFrame" KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0"/>
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="fadeInKeyFram" KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="1"/>
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="fadeOutKeyFrame" KeyTime="0:0:12" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

What I'd like to do is update the `KeyTime` values of the `LinearDoubleKeyFrame` elements from the UserControl code behind in C#.

I thought maybe I could do this by referencing those elements by their `x:Name` but I'm not having much success. I also thought maybe I could bind the values to a field in the code behind, but no success there either.

Has anyone got any clues to push me in the right direction.

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How have you tried to reference the `LinearDoubleKeyFrame` objects in code?

I think you need to do something like:

```
var storyboard = (Storyboard)FindResource("onLoadeducLogo");
var animation = (DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames)storyboard.Children[0];
var keyframe1 = animation.KeyFrames[0];

keyframe1.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1)); // 1 second
```

Comment: brilliant, spot on. My mistake was trying to FindResource on "pauseKeyFrame" - of course now I see your answer I realise that the Storyboard is the resource. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Image creatureImage = new Image();    
Storyboard fadeInFadeOut = new Storyboard();

    DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames dbAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
                dbAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
                LinearDoubleKeyFrame lDKF1 = new LinearDoubleKeyFrame();
                lDKF1.Value = 1;
                lDKF1.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
                dbAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(lDKF1);
                //
                LinearDoubleKeyFrame lDKF2 = new LinearDoubleKeyFrame();
                lDKF2.Value = 0.6;
                lDKF2.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
                dbAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(lDKF2);
                //
                LinearDoubleKeyFrame lDKF3 = new LinearDoubleKeyFrame();
                lDKF3.Value = 1;
                lDKF3.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
                dbAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(lDKF3);
                //
                LinearDoubleKeyFrame lDKF4 = new LinearDoubleKeyFrame();
                lDKF4.Value = 0;
                lDKF4.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                dbAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(lDKF4);

                Storyboard.SetTarget(dbAnimation, creatureImage);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dbAnimation, new PropertyPath(Image.OpacityProperty));
                fadeInFadeOut.Children.Add(dbAnimation);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps some explanation would add context to your post. Thanks for taking the time to answer!