# How would I convert WPF storyboard code to VB.NET or C#.NET so that I can in the future create the story board in code

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, storyboard

I have a sample story board that I would like to know how to implement using code only but I am having trouble figuring it out. Here is the WPF/XAML, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
        WindowStyle="None"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Transparent" Topmost="True" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Canvas Name="canvas1">
        <Button Canvas.Left="145" Canvas.Top="155" Content="Button" Height="23" Name="Button1" Width="75">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Button1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" AutoReverse="true" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="100"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:05" Value="300"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:10" Value="100"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetName="Button1"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                From="100" To="600" Duration="0:0:10" AutoReverse="true" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetName="Button1"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                From="100" To="600" Duration="0:0:10" AutoReverse="true" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: There is a comprehensive example in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far? What part are you having trouble with?

There are a few good examples on this page: http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2006102701.aspx

Comment: Thank you! This really helped, but I am still trying to figure out how to declare keyframes, which this article does not help with.

Comment: Would this answer help you as well? Of course, you'll have to declare your keyframes and add them to the animation (instead of looking for them in the resources) but the first answer shows how to setup a basic keyframe from timespane. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426596/update-a-lineardoublekeyframe-keytime-value-from-code